# Fading static Google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, fade

Is there a way to fade the edges of the map to white color in the image generated by Google static maps API V3?

Comment: i believe you can stack a div with a gradient on top of the static map

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing but was looking to see if there are parameters we can pass to Google static image url that does it for us